# Modules (since C++20) are not working with g++ 13.1.1

Tags: c++, error-handling, module, gcc-warning

I wanted to get started learning more about modules in C++.
I visited cppreference.com and observed how they work. But on my machine, they just don't.

I copied the first example of cppreference.com:

```
// helloworld.cpp
export module helloworld; // module declaration
 
import <iostream>;        // import declaration
 
export void hello()       // export declaration
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
}
```

```
// main.cpp
import helloworld; // import declaration
 
int main()
{
    hello();
}
```

When compiling with g++ -std=c++20 I got the following error message:

```
main.cpp:1:1: error: ‘import’ does not name a type
    1 | import helloworld;
      | ^~~~~~
main.cpp:1:1: note: C++20 ‘import’ only available with ‘-fmodules-ts’
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:3: error: ‘hello’ was not declared in this scope
    5 |   hello();
      |   ^~~~~
helloworld.cpp:1:1: warning: keyword ‘export’ is deprecated, and is ignored
    1 | export module helloworld;
      | ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:1:8: error: ‘module’ does not name a type
    1 | export module helloworld;
      |        ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:1:8: note: C++20 ‘module’ only available with ‘-fmodules-ts’
helloworld.cpp:3:1: error: ‘import’ does not name a type
    3 | import <iostream>;
      | ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp:3:1: note: C++20 ‘import’ only available with ‘-fmodules-ts’
helloworld.cpp:5:1: warning: keyword ‘export’ is deprecated, and is ignored
    5 | export void hello() {
      | ^~~~~~
helloworld.cpp: In function ‘void hello()’:
helloworld.cpp:6:8: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
    6 |   std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
      |        ^~~~
helloworld.cpp:1:1: note: ‘std::cout’ is defined in header ‘<iostream>’; did you forget to ‘#include <iostream>’?
  +++ |+#include <iostream>
    1 | export module helloworld;
```

As it is suggested in the error-log, I tried running the code with the following compiler flag:
-fmodules-ts: The error message after I run this command looks like this:

```
In module imported at main.cpp:1:1:
helloworld: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
helloworld: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/helloworld.gcm’
helloworld: note: imports must be built before being imported
helloworld: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
In module imported at helloworld.cpp:3:1:
/usr/include/c++/13.1.1/iostream: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/13.1.1/iostream: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/./usr/include/c++/13.1.1/iostream.gcm’
/usr/include/c++/13.1.1/iostream: note: imports must be built before being imported
/usr/include/c++/13.1.1/iostream: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
```

Clangd prompts: Header file  cannot be imported because it is not known to be a header unit.

My question is:
Can I somehow resolve this error? Should I even care about modules in C++? I never saw any source code where someone made use of this concept. Thanks for any help in advance!!!

Comment: Compiler-support is still unreliable, so modules are currently not really viable in production, IMO.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Of course! I ran: g++ main.cpp helloworld.cpp -fmodules-ts -o main

Comment: @bitmask Ok thanks! I'll wait another 3 years then... ;)

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: What is your complete command line? Have you tried reversing the order of the two .cpp files?

Comment: Yeah. But that doesn't make a difference. In my main.cpp, the module is not even found.. It's probably just not supported as @bitmask said I would guess.

Comment: Seems like you might also have to build an iostream module yourself. [Compiling C++20 program that uses modules with Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428832/compiling-c20-program-that-uses-modules-with-ubuntu-22-04)  With C++23 you will get an `import std;`, but we are not quite there yet,

Comment: @BoP Thanks for providing the link. I'll look into it ;)